# How to avoid "as any" in nested TypeScript type predicate functions?

Tags: typescript, types, factory

I'm working on a factory to create class instances from typed objects in TypeScript that I am receiving through my server API.
In order to know what instance to create I'm using type predicate functions.
The question is, how do I properly nest them without using `any`?

```
interface A { ... }
class B implements A { ... }
class C implements A { ... }

class Factory {
    public createA(serializable: any): A {
        if(isSerializableB(serializable)) return new B(serializable);
        if(isSerializableC(serializable)) return new C(serializable);
        throw new UnknownSerializableError();
    }
}

type SerializableA = { one: string }
type SerializableB = SerializableA & { two: number }
type SerializableC = SerializableA & { three: string | null }

function isSerializableA(thing: any): thing is SerializableA
{
    if(typeof thing !== "object" || thing === null) return false;
    if(typeof thing["one"] !== "string") return false;
    return true;
}

function isSerializableB(thing: any): thing is SerializableB
{
    if(!isSerializableA(thing)) return false;
    // TypeScript now assumes that thing is a SerializableA.
    
    if(typeof (thing as any)["two"] !== "number") return false;
    //               ^^^^^^ I don't want to have to do this.

    return true;
}

function isSerializableC(thing: any): thing is SerializableC
{
    if(!isSerializableA(thing)) return false;
    ...
}
```

Is there something wrong with my approach? I'd like to reuse the code of isSerializableA and not recheck the properties in the other type predicate functions but also avoid the use of `as any` or is that considered appropriate for this purpose?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL8KKm) solve your problem? If yes I will write up an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That helps indeed! Thank you very much. I haven't thought that "in" would work here. So TypeScript does not care if the property is actually in the type?

Comment: Yes, you can consider that as another type guard, like `typeof` for example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using type assertion, you can use the `in` operator to check whether the object has some key. In your case, it is `'two' in thing`. This will assign `unknown` to the `thing.two`, and the only thing left is just to check the type to be number as you already do.

```
type SerializableA = { one: string };
type SerializableB = SerializableA & { two: number };
type SerializableC = SerializableA & { three: string | null };

function isSerializableA(thing: any): thing is SerializableA {
  if (typeof thing !== 'object' || thing === null) return false;
  if (typeof thing['one'] !== 'string') return false;
  return true;
}

function isSerializableB(thing: any): thing is SerializableB {
  if (!isSerializableA(thing)) return false;

  if ('two' in thing && typeof thing.two !== 'number') return false;

  return true;
}
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL8KKm)